# Ceiling fan with two wall switches

Tags: ceiling-fan

I'm putting up a new ceiling fan. There are four cables in the ceiling and two wall switches. Black and white for one cable goes to each wall switch. The other two cables use only the black wire and one goes to each wall switch. So each switch has two black wires and one white, and there are four black wires and two white in the ceiling.

The old fan had three of the black wires twisted together with the black wire from the fan. The two white wires were twisted together with the white wire from the fan. The remaining black wire was attached to the blue wire on the fan.

My new ceiling fan has a remote. The remote sensor only has one black and one white wire for input from the house.

How do I attach these four cables to the remote sensor?

Answer (score 2):

Wire it using the black and white that were attached to the fan, and cap off the black that was attached to the blue (using a twist-on wire connector, or other approved means).

Note that the switch that used to turn the light on, will do nothing. And the switch that used to turn the fan on, will send power to the remote module or not.  So you'll want to leave the "fan" switch always in the ON position, so that the remote can control the fan/light.